# RTMFP successful connection ratio or percentage; AKA Adobe Cirrus, Stratus, LCCS

Tags: flash, p2p, soundcloud-stratus, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

Do you have actual experience with users establishing Adobe Flash RTMFP P2P connections in the real world?

I've heard a couple of people say only 50% succeed, but that sounds suspiciously low and the people saying that are probably all repeating the same rumor. My own very limited tests with various friends & colleagues work 100% of the time, as long as they have Flash Player 10, but that's obviously not right either.

Do you have some data from a largish test or deployment of home/corporate users?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Cirrus works on any NAT network which means almost 100% of the current ISP set-top-boxes and most of internets home users.

In corporate secured environnements, RTMFP may not work because it implies unrestricted UDP traffic or custom PROXY servers setups.

More technical infos here : 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_cirrus_app.html

ChatRoulette used RTMFP and proved its reliability

Comment: Doesnt chatroulette use a backup RTMP/FMS setup?

Answer (score 1):

After a few over-the-internet tests, using two domestic routers and a 3g dongle, one in three passed the dreaded http://cc.rtmfp.net/ test with no red light. So no go for me really, shame.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have actual experience with users establishing Adobe Flash
>   RTMFP P2P connections in the real world?

Yes , I created a website where users can do a Face 2 Face conferencing and it was working great. I was out of funds and i had to take down my website.

What i wanted to tell you is .. It really works great.

> Do you have some data from a largish test or deployment of
>   home/corporate users?

Visit http://omegle.com , they use purely RTMFP whereas Chatroulette.com uses RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

If have 3 home computer. It does not work between my home computers. If I remote access into a box on the other side of the country then it works.

It does not work in LAN because it does not support uPNP.